# I want to learn Kapow tool to migrate content from SDL Tridion 2011 to Web 8.5

Tags: migration

I want to learn Kapow tool to migrate content from SDL Tridion 2011 to Web 8.5. 
please suggest guides, blogs, videos, PDFs to understand this tool.

Comment: Thankyou for your perceptive response on AEM Content Migration. In my point of view, embarking on AEM content migration is conducting a systematic process with meticulous precision, we facilitate the seamless transfer of valuable content. This strategic approach involves careful coordination to ensure a fluid transition, prioritizing excellence at every step. This process involves transferring data from one Adobe Experience Manager instance to another, ensuring a smooth transition without compromising data integrity or user experiences. An interesting fact is that organizations adopting AEM co

Comment: The question is about Tridion Sites, rather than AEM (Adobe Experience Manager, I presume).

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to use available tools within Tridions (8.5 and 2011), you can use combination of import/export services and Content Porter.
So you can use Content Porter to export data from Tridion 2011, and use import/export service to import data in 8.5

For importing into Web 8.5, please check [this documentation.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-E2FE4BC2-C9EA-4FFA-A8E0-4C667BC5BD42)

For Content Porter 2013, please check [following documentation.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_ContentPorter_2013&lang=en-US#docid=concept_950156FA41854986AAEDFEB4D49048F9&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=map_931BDF60B74F4E29916F7E9E76FA9BB4.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_950156FA41854986AAEDFEB4D49048F9)

For Content Porter 2011, please check [following documentation.](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_ContentPorter_2009_SP2&lang=en-US#docid=concept_950156FA41854986AAEDFEB4D49048F9&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=map_931BDF60B74F4E29916F7E9E76FA9BB4.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_950156FA41854986AAEDFEB4D49048F9)

Answer (score 0):

I Think I might be late in answering this question, however I have done this kind of implementation in the past using Tridion core services and Robots of Kapow. This should follow ETL type implementation Extract , Transform and Load

Documentation for creating Kapow robots is provided by Kofax only, details for creating robots would be in Kapow user Guide.

- Extract Data using Tridion Core-Services of 2011.
- Store data in Custom DB used by Kapow to Custom DB.
- Transform Data (required in our case since we had to change schema root name and also
  we were planning to have different blueprint heirarchy).
- Create items using Separate robots using web 8.5 services.

  Create data using core-service of

**Challenges/ Lessons learned**

- Kapow does not support multipart responses of SOAP, create a small
  .net APP to download and upload the data of binary types (e.g. images/pdf)
- You will have to use legacy type of robots to call SOAP web-services.
- Make sure to take care of dependencies and only create items which are dependent in our case we had cyclic dependencies also like component a dependent on B and B on A.
- Also make sure to consider blueprint heirarchy while exporting and importing.

**Alternate Approach**

- Migrate the DB as is and create scripts in new CMS to syncronize content.
- Hire someone non-technical and create items from scratch.

Depending on how complex schemas you have in the system and how much time you have to implement the project you can select your option.

Comment: thank you for the details. it helps

Answer (score -2):

Please find below small description about kapow tool migration.

http://staging.kapowsoftware.com/solutions/content-migration/tridion.php.

I don’t think this tool supports SDL Tridion 2011 to SDL Web 8.5 Migration.

Please refer below hyperlink explain details upgrade 2011 to SDL Web 8.5

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-00D51AA4-1E17-4466-9183-F5F4932E553C

Comment: @Subhankar: thank you very much for the information. it helps.